# swift socket io connects to server but manager and engine are being released

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to make an super basic swift app that connects to my node backend socket.io server but when I run the following code I get a long error, which can be seen below. On the backend, it says that the app connected to the server, but when I try to emit any events, I get another error which is also below.

**swift code:**

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var messagesBody: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var newMessageInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newMessageSubmit: UIButton!

var socket:SocketIOClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/chat.html?name=developer&room=test")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    self.socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/")

    establishSocketConnection()

    newMessageSubmit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendNewMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func establishSocketConnection() {
    self.socket.connect()
    self.socket.on("connect") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
        print("connected to external server")
    }
}

func cloesSocketConnection() {
    self.socket.disconnect()
}

@objc func sendNewMessage() {
    let newMessageContent = newMessageInput.text!
    print("Sending message..." + newMessageContent)
    self.socket.emit("createMessage", newMessageContent)
}
}
```

**main error:**

```
2018-02-07 17:53:33.809954-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] [MC] Lazy 
loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-07 17:53:33.811229-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] [MC] Loaded 
MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-07 17:53:33.915820-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketIOClient{/swift}: Handling event: statusChange with data: 
[connecting]
2018-02-07 17:53:33.916535-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketIOClient{/swift}: Joining namespace /swift
2018-02-07 17:53:33.918305-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. 
Connecting
2018-02-07 17:53:33.918627-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketManager: Adding engine
2018-02-07 17:53:33.921886-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://localhost:3000/chat.html?
name=developer&room=test
2018-02-07 17:53:33.922020-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEngine: Handshaking
2018-02-07 17:53:33.922060-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketIOClient{/swift}: Adding handler for event: connect
2018-02-07 17:53:33.922966-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketManager: Manager is being released
2018-02-07 17:53:33.924349-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET 
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
2018-02-07 17:53:34.014299-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2018-02-07 17:53:34.016531-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 
97:0{"sid":"DRRfs3CyuXRDeYVIAAAA","upgrades":
["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
2018-02-07 17:53:34.022590-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"DRRfs3CyuXRDeYVIAAAA","upgrades":
["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
2018-02-07 17:53:34.045912-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
2018-02-07 17:53:34.046635-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
2018-02-07 17:53:34.048335-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
2018-02-07 17:53:34.049790-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2018-02-07 17:53:34.050572-0500 chat-app[78163:6477498] LOG 
SocketEngine: Engine is being released
```

**second error:**

```
2018-02-07 17:53:37.918418-0500 chat-app[78163:6477441] LOG 
SocketIOClient{/swift}: Handling event: error with data: ["Tried 
emitting createMessage when not connected"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare `SocketManager` as a stored property, if not will be deallocated just after the `viewDidLoad`.

> Sockets created through the manager are retained by the manager. So at the very least, a single strong reference
>   to the manager must be maintained to keep sockets alive.

So you might use the following:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {
   //... stuff here ...//
   var manager:SocketManager?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/chat.html?name=developer&room=test")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
   }
```

### }

moreover please change the order inside of:

```
func establishSocketConnection() {
    self.socket.on("connect") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
        print("connected to external server")
    }
    self.socket.connect()
}
```

Comment: I updated it to that and it still gives the same two errors. I updated my code above

Comment: @ChrisWindsor please check my edit: `self.socket.connect()` after `socket.on`

Comment: I resolved it because I copied your code directly and you had "socketManager" and "manager" and I just caught that. Thank you for your help. you should edit your response for future readers

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini how to find the correct server url, if server url is not working?? this is my url:- "ws//example-ws.herokuapp.com/". is there anything I'm missing ?? or need to check ?